# Changing Email subject for outlook

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, gmail

I was asked if changing an email's subject is possible when someone receives it in Outlook. Is it?

I was thinking it may be. The same way user agents are used for browsers maybe? I'm pretty new to emails **but searching on the internet didn't help and I've already spent a few hours doing that.**

You don't have to solve it for me, just point me to the right direction would suffice. Either way it's something I would like to learn doing.

TL;DR Email subject text change based on recipient (Outlook specifically).

Comment: Hello marcus. I did try Google, but nothing is coming up. I've spent the last hour trying to find it. I wouldn't post on Stack Overflow if Google came up with something. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email clients do not support dynamic code, so you can't do this with client-side JavaScript.

SMTP servers sending email have no way of knowing which client will be used to open the email. (They don't send email in response to the email client asking for it).

What you want is impossible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.